# Language/ Framework for dialog system, for ex. cars or intelligent houses

Tags: c, jakarta-ee, modal-dialog

I am interested in developing dialog systems for cars and houses. Let us say while driving you can tell your board computer to call your colleague or when coming back home you can say the light to turn itself on. So just easy things, no science fiction.

Does anybody know what is the most used language, technology for such tasks. Is it java, C or other special frameworks??

Any hel would be appreciated.

Regards,

Horace

Comment: "So just easy things, no science fiction.". Yeah. All that's easy.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment Charlie.